# El valor del Datepicker (Daterangepicker) transformado a "Date" me muestra siempre la fecha de hoy

Tags: javascript, jquery

Saludos,
Tengo un Datepicker el cual si recojo el valor directamente (como string)
    `var Data = $("#txtExpDataInici").val();` me coje bien los valores de la fecha, pero si lo transformo en fecha   `Date($("#txtExpDataInici").val());` siempre me devuelve la fecha de hoy elja la fecha que elija...
¿Alguien sabe que puede pasar?

Comment: ¿Estás hablando del Datepicker de jQuery UI?

Comment: @Darkhogg  http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: Especifícalo en tu pregunta, implementaciones de Datepickets hay chorrocientos millones y ninguno aquí podemos leerte la mente (que yo sepa).

Comment: Si inspeccionas el val() que recibes como es la fecha? que formato tiene.  No evaluaste usar la libreria moment.js   http://momentjs.com/  esta podria ser util para parsear la fecha, en lugar de usar el Date()

Comment: Solucionado con el momentsjs, gracias!

Comment: @Xavier puse la recomendacion como respuesta, asi no queda como simple comentario, mas que nada sabiendo que resolvio el problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendaria usar la libreria [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) esta podría ser util para parsear la fecha, en lugar de usar el `Date()`.

Un ejemplo

```
var fecha = $("#txtExpDataInici").val();
var expDataInici = moment(fecha);
```

tambien puedes indicarle algun formato

```
var expDataInici = moment(fecha, "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
var fecha = new Date($("#txtExpDataInici").val());
```

Si el valor recogido por el Datepicker por ejemplo es : 
03/04/2016

"fecha" valdrá ahora:
 Fri Mar 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)